# Oracle BPEL DB Adapter constraint exception when writing in two tables - suddenly broken

Tags: oracle, transactions, bpel

I've got a Oracle BPEL process running on WebLogic which is writing in two tables using Database Adapters.

There are two tables, TableA and TableB. TableB has a foreign key to TableA.

I the process I create an entry in TableA with A_ID. When I create an entry in TableB using A_ID as a FK I get a constraint exception.

What is weird, this worked last week and now, using the same data, I get the error.

The datasource is set up as a standard - non-XA datasource.

This is the exception that is thrown:

```
<env:Fault>
     <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Exception occured when binding was invoked.
      Exception occured during invocation of JCA binding: "JCA Binding execute of
      Reference operation 'insert' failed due to: DBWriteInteractionSpec Execute
      Failed Exception.
      insert failed. Descriptor name: [Datawarehouse.TableB].
      Caused by java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint 
      (DWH.TABLE_A_FK) violated - parent key not found
      .
      ". 
      The invoked JCA adapter raised a resource exception.
      Please examine the above error message carefully to determine a  resolution.
      </faultstring>
      <faultactor/>
      <detail>
        <exception>ORA-02291: integrity constraint (DWH.TABLE_A_FK) violated -     parent key not found</exception>
     </detail>
  </env:Fault>
```

Comment: Do you use association between tables (master-detail) while configure a DB adapter?

Comment: No I didn't. The process was running in production for years without a problem, so I didn't consider that.

Comment: Can you show your excepion.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Oracle BPEL. For some reason, either the insert onto Table A is not successful or the insert on to Table A is not visible to Table B (second insert being in a different transaction).